# How to add custom JavaScript to AMP HTML

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I do know how to use [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) to replicate the jQuery behaviour below;

```html
<script
  async 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
>
</script>
<script>
  $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
    $('.nav').toggle();
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });
</script>

<div class="menu-toggle"></div>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>no</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is jquery sufficient? I would think you also need `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js`

Comment: @RichardMatsen ,  thank you, how do I integrate the above jquery with Google amp? please help me

Comment: Standard jQuery is larger than allowed in `amp-script`. You have to compose your objective as a single JavaScript paragraph (JS without dependencies).

Comment: @RakyatMedan is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821363/6381711) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your custom JavaScript in AMP HTML, make use of [`<amp-script>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) component.

Below, your AMP HMTL code;

```html
<amp-script layout="container"
  script="toggle"
  class="amp-my-custom-script-menu">
  <div id="menu-toggle">Click to toggle nav class</div>
  <ul id="nav" class="nav-menu">
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>no</li>
  </ul>
</amp-script>
```

Then, your custom JavaScript - in the example, our custom JavaScript is used inline;

```html
<!-- It is important to note that the value of the type attribute for
your <script> needs to be "text/plain" a target attribute as "amp-script". -->
<script id="toggle"
  type="text/plain"
  target="amp-script">
  const menuToggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
  menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-menu-active');
  });
</script>
```

Please note that you reference your scripts by id (toggle).

Remember to include `amp-script` component in your AMP HTML .

```html
<!-- Important to add "amp-script" custom element reference in your <head> tag -->
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
```

---

TL;DR: The following is a full snippet showing how you can achieve that;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <!-- Important to add "amp-script" custom element reference -->
  <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
  <title>AMP with custom JavaScript for class toggle</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href=".">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Add your custom CSS here. -->
  <style amp-custom>
    .nav-menu {
      display: none;
    }
    .nav-menu-active {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- The hash of your script should be added here. -->
  <meta
    name="amp-script-src"
    content="sha384-YsM3ypHm0ggSSir6kuKl064hq6E0K_7esi9NeIOxfVqkKLgshY0dYBTdEBvB5UYx"
  >
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
<head>
<body>
  <amp-script layout="container"
    script="toggle"
    class="amp-my-custom-script-menu">
    <div id="menu-toggle">Click to toogle nav class</div>
    <ul id="nav" class="nav-menu">
      <li>ok</li>
      <li>no</li>
    </ul>
  </amp-script>
  <script id="toggle"
    type="text/plain"
    target="amp-script">
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
      nav.classList.toggle('nav-menu-active');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```